# Multiple classes mapping to the same table in Entity Framework 4.1 Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

I have a very simple model that maps to one table (Projects) in my database. I have chosen to abstract out images to its own class.

```
public class Project
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Image Images { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryImage { get; set; }
}
```

How would I go about wiring up my model to the table in the database using the code below:

```
public class Context : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        ????
    }
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You object model will be mapped to one single table as it stands now, no fluent API is required. Code First will automatically mark the Image class as a [Complex Type](http://weblogs.asp.net/manavi/archive/2010/12/11/entity-association-mapping-with-code-first-part-1-one-to-one-associations.aspx) based on conventions.

Answer (score 2):

```
public class Project
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Image Image { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public string Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public string PrimaryImage { get; set; }
}    

public class YourContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Project> Projects{ get; set; }        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ComplexType<Image>();
    }
}
```